# How to substract one DenseVector from another in Spark MLLib

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib

`a` and `b` are two `spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector`s:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector

...
val a = DenseVector(Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
val b = DenseVector(Array(2.0, 3.0, 1.0))
...
```

I want to get `c` as subtraction of `b` from `c`. How to do it?